# The scroll bar jumps a bit when I move the splitter up and down quickly tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

The scroll bar jumps a bit when I move the splitter up and down quickly

Do you have any idea how to fix it ?

I attach you code gui. You can run it and see it
The scroll bar jumps a bit when I move the splitter up and down quickly

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('900x650+0+0')
p2 = PanedWindow(root, orient=VERTICAL)
pw = PanedWindow(p2, orient='horizontal', showhandle=True, handlesize=15, sashwidth=5, height=450)

pw.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
pw.configure(sashrelief=RAISED)
p2.add(pw)
p2.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
p2.configure(sashrelief=RAISED)

p3 = PanedWindow(p2, height=10)
p3.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
p2.add(p3)
bottom_frame = tk.Frame(root)
log_frame = Frame(p3)
log_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
p3.add(log_frame)
log_frame.config(height=10)
verscrlbar_frame1 = Scrollbar(log_frame, orient="vertical")
horscrlbar_frame1 = Scrollbar(log_frame, orient="horizontal")

verscrlbar_frame1.pack(expand=False, side='right', fill='y')
horscrlbar_frame1.pack(expand=False, side='bottom', fill='x')
text = Text(log_frame, height="10", width=650)
text.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
text.config(xscrollcommand=horscrlbar_frame1.set)
text.config(yscrollcommand=verscrlbar_frame1.set)
text.config(state=DISABLED)
verscrlbar_frame1.config(command=text.yview)
horscrlbar_frame1.config(command=text.xview)


btn_save_cfg = ttk.Button(bottom_frame, text="Save configuration")
btn_save_cfg.pack(pady=20, expand=True, side=tk.LEFT)
btn_run = ttk.Button(bottom_frame, text="Run")
btn_run.pack(pady=20, expand=True, side=tk.LEFT)
bottom_frame.pack(expand=False, side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=BOTH)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It happens because everytime you change entry size, it recalculate position of scrollbar.  Somehow making it fixed by geometry placing probably going to solve your problem.

Comment: How to fix it ? I can't understand from your answer. @MustafaKÜÇÜKDEMİRCİ

Comment: Can you please fix the broken indentation of the code in your question?

Comment: Are we supposed to see this behavior only when there's no text in the text widget? I don't see anything unusual when I run your code.

Comment: Just copy as it is and run. Try on windows too.  Move the splitter up and down quickly a few times. @BryanOakley

Comment: I do not understand  how many PanedWindow u have pw, p2 and p3? u had 2 duplicated p2.add. I only saw one horizontal PanedWindow.

Comment: P2 - is the main , pw - is the top and p3 is the bottom. I add pw and p3 to p2 @toyotaSupra

Comment: I can see p3, but where is pw and p2? U had wrong object.

Comment: look at the beginning. Line 7-8. Do you run the gui ? @toyotaSupra

Comment: Hi Alex. I worked with panedwindows. The problem is not about scroll bars actually. I placed a label and text widget to test it. If you move quickly you can see that sometimes bottom of text widget get grayed sometimes which means that while it recalculates we see those. So, I found the problem but do not have the solution.

Comment: If I replaced Text with Label then it should be ok ? @MustafaKÜÇÜKDEMİRCİ

Comment: If you want to keep the "resizable" feature which means you need to use panedwindow, you will face this problem all the time.